# Add text in empty space in Joomla corpoboost theme

Tags: joomla-2.5, administration, basics

Please visit his link : http://naadiastrology.info/

On bottom you can see : "bottom menu". 
Below 6 links are there, below that some empty space is there.

How to add some text in those empty space?

Comment: I really think you need to get some tutorials and really learn joomla instead of filling stack exchange with lots of specific questions to the site you're trying to build.

Comment: hi, Thanks a lot, i will surely learn and avoid asking questions here.

Comment: Agree. This is not really a Joomla question, you're asking questions specific to your non-standard template

Comment: I would also suggest actually giving yourself a real username if you're going to participate here. That makes it feel less like you're just here to leach what you can and leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Module Manager, create a new Module and set the **type** to **Custom**.

Once done, open this module and you will see a big textarea allowing you to add any content you like.

You will need to set the position to **bottom-d** then save it.

Hope this helps

Comment: check it now, I added module name "space ", its displaying under fingerprint image, not under "bottom menu " . how to move under "bottom menu".

Comment: @user2384317 - Ok go to your Module Manager and you will see a module called "Be careful". This is in the position you want your custom module

Answer (score 2):

This image shows [all module positions available](http://themeforest.net/item/corpoboost-responsive-joomla-template-/full_screen_preview/3339973) in your template:

[image: Corpoboost module positions]